# Report Builder 3.0 - permit user to add data in after report generated

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Using Report Builder 3.0 against cubes which are produced overnight.

The report I'm designing is used to archive or transfer (physical) files for patients.  Users run the report, print it & then attach it to files that are then sent to a central area which will archive/send the files on.

The report has a number of parameters which is designed to return a single patient.  This all works fine.

One of the parameters (@prmReason) is a single choice on what is to happen to the files, eg, "Transfer" (transfer files to another office), "Archive - closed", "Archive - deceased", "Archive - excess" (office space is limited, so staff archive off 'older' files).

One of the fields returned is CloseReason.  This field always has a value.  If the field is empty in the database (as the client hasn't closed), then it will contain the value: "Unknown".

This field (amongst others) are either displayed or hidden, depending on @prmReason.  Again - all working without a problem.

Now for the tricky bit.
If the @prmReason = "Archive - closed" or "Archive - deceased" then the report will display CloseReason.
The problem is if CloseReason = "Unknown" then I need to know the why the file is closed & display it on the report.

I want users to be able to choose a value from a list of closure reasons.  I then want the choice to be displayed on the report.  Obviously if there is a genuine reason then display this value.

So the effect I'm after is:
User selects parameters & runs report.
Report then checks to see why report is being run (eg @prmReason).
If @prmReason =("Archive - closed" OR "Archive - deceased") AND CloseReason = "Unknown"
Then somehow produce a list of CloseReasons that the user can select.  This value is then displayed on the report.
I can even cope with it being a free text field.  Just something so that the central area can update the database if necessary & save a phone call/email etc.

(Yes, I realise that I can have the list as a series of tickboxes that the user ticks after the report is printed, but this would be a useful ability in other reports).

EDIT:  empty value of CloseReasons conflicted with stackoverflow formatting (sorry didn't review post properly).  Value is actually less then symbol then the word Unknown and then greater than symbol.  It doesn't really affect the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an additional hidden parameter.

If this parameter is **not** set then display an small table on your report that has a list of CloseReasons.

You then set table cell's action property to open the a report, choose your existing report as the report to open but this time you can pass a value for the final parameter, which,  as well as displaying the Close reason in your report, would also hide the close reason choices table described above.

**UPDATE** To make clear more clear.

The following is based on the Northwind sample database. I have a shared data source pointing to this database.

Create new report.

Add a data source pointing to the shared Northwind data source

Add a new data set pointing to the data source above with the following query

```
SELECT 
    EmployeeID,
    FirstName, LastName, Address, City, Country, Title, Notes
 FROM Employees
 WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
```

Add some of the fields to the report to show some basic info.

We now have a simple report with a single parameter `@EmployeeID`

Next we want to show some actions for each employee. For flexibility, I'm making this list dynamic based on the employee's `Country`. This list could be static.

Create a new dataset `dsActions` with the following query

```
    DECLARE @actions TABLE(ActionID int, ActionLabel varchar(20))

    -- Get employees country
    DECLARE @Country varchar(20) = (SELECT Country FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID)

    IF @Country = 'UK'
       BEGIN
          INSERT INTO @actions VALUES
          (1,'Sack them'),
          (2,'Buy them a pint'),
          (3,'Promote')
       END
    ELSE
       BEGIN
          INSERT INTO @actions VALUES
          (1,'Fire them'),
          (2,'High 5 them'),
          (3,'Ask them to run for office')
       END

SELECT * FROM @actions
```

Add a table to the report to show these values.

At the moment my design looks like this. (All the expressions are simple fields from the first dataset to show the employee details, nothing special)
[image]

And when I run it I get this.

[image]

OK, now all the basics are done, we need to be able to call this report again, but with an action already chosen. We'll make the actions table clickable and pass the action's label to the report. 
**It's the same report, we will only ever have a single report.**

First, add a new parameter called `action` to the report and make it hidden. Add a default value of 'noaction'.

Next we want to only show our actions table if the `action` parameter is set to 'noaction'. To do this, set the `Hidden` property of the action table (tablix) to the following

```
=Parameters!action.Value <> "noaction"
```

Next we want to add a text box that displays the result `action` parameter, but only when the `action` parameter is not `noaction`.

So add a text, set it's expression to `=Parameters!action.Value` and the hidden property to `=Parameters!action.Value = "noaction"`

Finally, we need to make our actions list call our report but with a specific action. To do this we need to modify the actions table.

*First save the report, whatever name you choose is the name you will select as the target report as the report will call itself.*

Right-click the cell that contains the `ActionLabel` and go to the text box properties.

Select the Action tab and then choose "Go to report". Choose the name of the report you are currently working on (this actual report as the report will call itself).

Set EmployeeID parameter to `[@EmployeeID]` and the `action` parameter to `[ActionLabel]`

*I've used the label for simplicity but you could pass the ActionID as long as you account for this in the text box that displays the action.*

Optionally you could format the text so it looks like a link,

The final design and action/parameter setup looks like this

[image]

When I first run the report I get the following...

[image]

As soon as I click one of the actions, I then get this...

[image]

Hopefully that's clear now.

Comment: Thanks Alan, but I'm not clear on this.  My original report contains parameters in order to produce the single record I'm after.  This may or may not have a valid CloseReasons value - I won't know until the report is produced.  I don't understand how I can set the action property to open this report & then pass the existing parameters (along with the CloseReason) to itself.  To me it seems like I'm running the report twice? First to find out if the value is valid & then again to add the (potential) missing value?  Yes?

Comment: I thought that was the workflow you were trying to create..Run report, see what options are available and then choose one of those options and print. I may have misunderstood.

Comment: Hi Alan.  Yes, you're correct - that is the workflow, but I'm misunderstanding something in your explanation.  To my thinking, that means that I'd have to have 2 copies of the report - one that the user selects the various parameters.  Once it's run & the report checks if CloseReasons is missing, then launches another version - which is identical to the first except it has the CloseReasons parameter.  The first report passes all the parameters the user has already selected to the second.  I don't think that's what you mean, but I just can't quite grasp what you're trying to explain.

Comment: I've update the answer to show a complete solution. Hopefully this is what you were looking for, or is close enough to get you going.

Comment: Hi Alan.  Wow.  Thanks for the explanation - that helped a huge amount & I can't wait to try it out.  Will feed back (so others can benefit!).

Comment: Hi Alan.  That was perfect!  yes, I'll need to do a bit of tweaking - but this is AMAZING.  Next time I'm over - yes - I'll happily buy you a pint!.